# Matching sentences (/bullet points) in two sets using NLP

Tags: natural-language-processing

I am working on a problem where I have two texts T1, T2. T1 contains some important points that I have entered. How can I make sure that T2 has those points? I am aware of the algorithms like cosine, jaccard, BERT for semantic similarity but the problem is that they apply to the whole text whereas I want point-wise similarity i.e. T2 must contain the T1 points although the order and words used may differ a bit.

By points I meant bullet points covering discrete concepts and I basically want to check how many discrete concepts in my T1's points are covered in T2 where they could be in a single sentence or spread out across multiple sentences.

Example:

So T1 could have the following two points:

- The Queen reigned from 1943 to 2022.
- The Queen was the second
  longest reigning monarch.

Now T2 could either be:

The Queen was the second longest reigning monarch with her reign spanning 1952 to 2022.

or

- The Queen reigned from 1952 to 2022.
- She was Britain's second longest monarch.

In both these cases, T2 should be considered to contain both points in T1.

Comment: what do you mean by points

Comment: @HadarSharvit edited to add an example.

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of both $T_1$ and $T_2$ is bullet points, I presume that the similarity between every pair of bullet points is a nice baseline. I'd go through various encoders and see how they compare.
Otherwise, if $T_2$ is a paragraph, maybe split it to sentences and treat those as bullet points.
Other option (which might be harder) is to fine-tune a language model with the following input and label:
suppose the bullet points are $\{bp_1^1,...,bp_1^n\}$ for $T_1$ and $\{bp_2^1,...,bp_2^m\}$ for $T_2$, we can formulate a prompt as

> Input: `text1`=$bp_1^i$, `text2`=$bp_2^j$
>
> Output: `True` *iff* `text2` in `text1`

Where the targets were tagged by you apriori

Comment: How to split into sentences when the same point could be spread across two or more sentences in T2? Also how to order the points in T2 after the split?

Comment: And what do you mean by "language model"?

Comment: Lastly, this won't be contributing anything new to preexisting research right?